# Firebase how to update child value in javasscript

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

i want to to update child value depending on categoryId. I tried following this tutorial [Firebase DB - How to update particular value of child in Firebase Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40589397/firebase-db-how-to-update-particular-value-of-child-in-firebase-database). It’s work, but it’s not storing in the same ref. It’s store in another ref.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaqjD.png

```
firebase.database().ref('usuario')
                    .on('value',event =>{
                        event.forEach(user =>{
                            user.child('eventos').forEach(evento =>{
                                if (evento.val().categoryId === payload.id){
                                  //Here is where i try to update the childe value, in my case category
                                    let ref = firebase.database().ref('usuario/'+user.key+'/'+evento.key+'/'+evento.val().category)
                                        .set(payload.name)
                                    console.log(ref)
                                }

                            })
                        });

                    });
```

Comment: add an image before update

Comment: @PeterHaddad I added the link of image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 problems:
1.You forgot to add "\eventos" on you child path.
2.dont use .set(), because it will delete all the other data.
Instead of .set() use .update().
Try this code:

```
firebase.database().ref('usuario')
                    .on('value',event =>{
                        event.forEach(user =>{
                            user.child('eventos').forEach(evento =>{
                                if (evento.val().categoryId === payload.id){
                                  //Here is where i try to update the childe value, in my case category
                                    let ref = firebase.database().ref('usuario/'+user.key+'/eventos/'+evento.key+'/'+evento.val().category)
                                        .update(payload.name)
                                    console.log(ref)
                                }

                            })
                        });

                    });
```

Let me know if it still dont work