# Firebase realtime database Rest API refer object

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using firebase rest API in my project. I have following data in firebase realtime database.

```
Users {
  -asgfhgkho {
     name:Rahul Vyas
    email: imrahulvyaas@gmail.com
   }
}
History {
-124lahsfaksfh {
  players {
   -asdfghjikjdlk {
     name:Rahul Vyas
     email: imrahulvyaas@gmail.com }
   }
  }
 }
```

Now my question is if I update the name property using patch. How the name will be reflected under History->players->{playerId}->name. How we can refer an user object in multiple different nodes. Note I'm using firebase rest API.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to update those names yourself by writing code for it.

Since you must know the exact path to perform write to it, that means you'll typically:

1. Perform a query to determine what nodes to update
2. Perform an update for each, or a single multi-location update

Comment: but there could be 100's of location. Isn't there any way like we do in MySQL where user object is automatically fetched ? Like we set userId only at all other location and when we fetch from firebase it automatically fetch user object.. Is it possible ?

Comment: Firebase does not support update queries. To write to a location, you must know the exact path to that location. Firebase also doesn't support server-side joins when reading data (which is what I think you're describing in your comment). But client-side joins are common, and not nearly as slow as many developers initially think due to the fact that Firebase pipelines the requests over a single connection. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786

Comment: but on client side how we will keep track of user's all nodes ?

Comment: can you explain point 1 in your answer ?

Perform a query to determine what nodes to update - any pseudo code for this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40589397/firebase-db-how-to-update-particular-value-of-child-in-firebase-database

Comment: thanks for the answer. It looks doable. I'm just wondering that is it possible to get all the nodes with their path using Firebase rest API ? Any hint for this ? I mean with reference to my question in the main post.

Comment: Sure it is possible to [perform a query over the REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-filtering. What problem do you have? Did you try anything yet?

Comment: No, I haven't tried it yet. Will let you know If I stuck somewhere. Thanks for helping me out.