# I want to use Firebase in Android Studio to change the value from 'false' to 'true'

Tags: firebase

```
      databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("CurrentUser").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("MyOrder");
  

databaseReference.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("").setValue("true").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
           @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
             }
    });
```

I want the value to change from 'false' to 'true' and be saved.

Comment: How many children exist under `MyOrder` node?

Comment: Did you save those pushed IDs somewhere in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *Yes* or *No*, use 0 (zero) and 1 (one) – or maybe use boolean. In order to update a value, Firebase has method `update()`, so use that.
Maybe this will help: [Firebase DB - How to update particular value of child in Firebase Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40589397/firebase-db-how-to-update-particular-value-of-child-in-firebase-database)